# Extract days, hours and seconds from a list of datetimes

Tags: python, datetime, python-itertools

I have a very long list of `datetime`s chronologically sorted (monotonically increasing if you prefer). Imagine something like that:

```
import datetime
dates=[datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(xx) for xx in xrange(huge_number)]
```

the difference with respect to my real list is that the timestep is not always constant, and there are usually gaps in between seconds, hours, or days.

What I want to do is make a user choose (via a PyQt4 GUI) a precise datetime, and what I was guessing to do this:

1. get all different days contained in `datetimes_list`
2. for each day, build a list with all different hours corresponding to this day
3. for each hour, get the the full list of instants corresponding to this hour

For sure, I can do this with some for/if loops but I was wondering if there is an efficient and compact way to do this, maybe using `itertools` and `groupby` iterator. But if I really don't feel comfortable with `itertools`, so if someone has an idea that would be great!

Comment: You can find specific datetimes in your sorted list using [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/bisect.html). You should (probably) build your 2 and 3 lists dynamically, in response to the user selecting an entry from the previous list.

Comment: Note: the local time is not necessarily monotonous (e.g., due to DST transitions) and therefore the results of `fromtimestamp()` are not necessarily increasing in your case (it depends on your local timezone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a dictionary or an OrderedDict:

```
import collections
d=collections.OrderedDict()
for e in dates:
    d.setdefault(e.strftime('%Y%m%d'),collections.OrderedDict()).setdefault(e.strftime('%H'), []).append(e.strftime('%H%M%S'))
```

Or in a less compact but more readable formulation:

```
import collections
d=collections.OrderedDict()
for e in dates:
    day, hour, full_time=e.strftime('%Y%m%d'), e.strftime('%H'), e.strftime('%H%M%S')
    d.setdefault(day,collections.OrderedDict()).setdefault(hour, []).append(full_time)
```

It will result in an O(1) access time for any date selection / any hour selection

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That works great for me!

Comment: Cool. Would be great if you mark this answer as ok.